# redux-toolkit extraReducers not being invoked

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying out the createAsyncThunk but can't get the extraReducers to fire. Here is what I have right now:

```
export const getAllAgents = createAsyncThunk(
  "getAllAgents",
  async (token: string) => {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    const response = await fetch(`${API.endpoint}/data/agent`, {
      method: "get",
      headers,
      redirect: "follow",
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log("Response in thunk: ", { data });
    return data;
  }
);

export const agentSlice = createSlice({
  name: "agentSlice",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers:
    //builder call back required for typesafety
    //https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#type-safety-with-extrareducers
    (builder) => {
      console.log(createNewAgent.fulfilled);
      builder.addCase(createNewAgent.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        console.log("fulfilled action", { action });
      });
      console.log(getAllAgents.fulfilled);
      builder.addCase(getAllAgents.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.agents = action.payload.agents;
      });
    },
});
```

I also see the fulfilled action being called in the dev tools:
[image]

What is amiss?

Comment: Yes! That's what it tured out to be!

Comment: I made a similar mistake and wondered why it isn't working.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. My mistake was that I was adding reducers outside of extraReducers.

This was wrong:

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,
  extraReducers: {
    [login.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {},
   },
   [signUp.fulfilled]: state => {}
}
```

Comment: Mine was close to this except I had accidentally added an extra curly bracket after reducers and so my extraReducers were actually in my reducers, lol

Comment: can we use reducers and extrareducers both in createSlice() function ? i.e.  extrareducers for API call and set data. and reducers will be used for functions for internal state management

Comment: @nmu this happened to me today! xd

Comment: I feel a deep connection to u @EAlexisMT <3

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar problem. It turned out I forgot to add a reducer. Try this.

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    theme: themeSlice,
    user: userSlice // here
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for me I needed to remove the curly brackets from the import

```
import  slice  from './slice';
```

instead of

```
import {slice} from './slice'
```